# spring data JPA null primary key error

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Here is my data entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotel")
@Data
public class Hotel  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "hotel_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_price")
    private RoomPrice roomPrice;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "room_price")
@Data
public class RoomPrice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "room_price_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int roomPriceId;

    @Column(name = "price")
    @Min(0)
    private double price;

    @Column(name = "currency_type")
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 3, max = 3)
    private String currency;
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_price (
  room_price_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  price         SMALLINT,
  currency_type VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE hotel
  ADD
  COLUMN room_price INTEGER REFERENCES room_price (room_price_id);
```

`hotel.setRoomPrice(price); hotelDao.save(hotel);` throw room_price_id null value [error message](https://imgur.com/ZICH3sJ).
With `cascade.all`, when storing a hotel entity, it should also store price entity. What have I been doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy, you should use `serial` or `bigserial` type for `room_price_id` to let Postgres to auto generate your primary key.